# Remote Debug Symbol file format

Tags: delphi, remote-debugging, file-format, debug-symbols

Does anyone know about the file format for the remote debug symbol file
(Project -> Options -> Linking -> Include Remote Debug Symbols) ?

Comment: Did you ever find anything out about this? I'm interested too - three years later...